# Google Cloud "maximum_persistent_disks_size_gb" Issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have problem with appengine of google the disk is exceeded "How can I apply new disk to an instance?" I'm using appspot.

error A:

> Editing VM instance "instance-1" failed. Error: Exceeded limit 'maximum_persistent_disks_size_gb' on resource 'instance-1'. Limit: 10240.0

error B:

> LIMIT_EXCEEDED: Exceeded limit 'maximum_persistent_disks_size_gb' on resource 'instance-1'. Limit: 10240.0

Answer (score 2):

It probably has nothing to do with quota.  I'm guessing that's an old instance.

See the "Note" section under Limits on this page:  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs

It says:

> Note: If you created an instance before March 30, 2016, it might retain an older 10 TB limit for total persistent disk space. Recreate those instances to update their limits to the new 64 TB limit per instance.

-Ray

Answer (score 0):

You might be going out of the project's Compute Engine quota for the zone.  Visit the [quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) to see if you are and request higher quota.

Comment: quota page I went through the process with google replying but it was useless any other way around.